# How to catch newlines in user input

Tags: grep, xargs, read, input

I want to do something with user input to use in `grep`. Like, instead of

```
uin="first\nsecond\n"
printf $uin | grep d
```

which outputs `second`, I want to have the user input it, like

```
read uin
```

where the user could input `"first\nsecond\n"`. Then the variable could be used in the `grep` line like above. Or if the user could input actual returns after entering `first` and `second`, that would be filled in as `\n` that would work also. This is meant to be run from the cli. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
echo>&2 "Please enter a multiline string, Ctrl-D, twice if not on an empty line to end:"
input=$(cat)
printf 'You entered: <%s>\n'
```

Note that `$(...)` strips all trailing newline characters, so that can't be used to input text that ends in newline characters.

To read exactly two lines, just call `read` twice:

```
IFS= read -r first
IFS= read -r second
printf 'You entered: <%s\n%s>\n' "$first" "$second"
```

To input one line and have the `\n`, `\a`, `\x45`, `\0123`¹... sequences expanded in it:

```
IFS= read -r line
expanded_line=$(printf %b "$line")
printf 'You entered: <%s>\n' "$expanded_line"
```

Or with `bash`/`zsh` or recent versions of ksh93u+m, avoiding the stripping of trailing newline characters:

```
IFS= read -r line
printf -v expanded_line %b "$line"
printf 'You entered: <%s>\n' "$expanded_line"
```

In any case

- the syntax to read a line is [`IFS= read -r line`](/q/209123), not <strike>`read line`</strike>
- [parameter expansions must be quoted in POSIX shells such as `bash`](/q/68694).
- the first argument of `printf` is the  format, you shouldn't have external data there.

---

<sup>¹ Beware that's the `echo` style of expansion where octal sequences need a leading 0 (`\0ooo`), not the usual `\ooo` one as in the C language and as also recognised in the format argument of `printf`.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner bash script of `grep d` suffices.
It will read stdin until user enters final line of ctrl-D.

Or put `cat` into a script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

PATTERN=${1:-d}
TMP=/tmp/user_input.txt

cat > ${TMP}

grep "${PATTERN}" ${TMP}

rm ${TMP}
```

Then you can sort, awk, or otherwise slice-n-dice the input repeatedly.

Comment: If you copy/paste that into http://shellcheck.net it'll tell you of some issues. See also [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization).